# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Java MapReduce Application Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
// bro lets see this new package works or not. 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class RainfallAnalyzer {
    // mapper class wala part 
    public static class RainfallMapper 
          extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private Text state = new Text();
        private IntWritable rainfall = new IntWritable();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

            String stateName = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String cityName = tokenizer.nextToken();
            int rainfallDepth = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());

            state.set(stateName);
            rainfall.set(rainfallDepth);

            context.write(state, rainfall);
        }
    }
// reducer class wala part 
    public static class RainfallReducer 
            extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
        private Text result = new Text();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int totalRainfall = 0;
            int largestRainfall = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int smallestRainfall = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                int rainfall = val.get();
                totalRainfall += rainfall;
                largestRainfall = Math.max(largestRainfall, rainfall);
                smallestRainfall = Math.min(smallestRainfall, rainfall);
            }

            String output = totalRainfall + " " + largestRainfall + " " + smallestRainfall;
            result.set(output);

            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Rainfall Analyzer");

        job.setJarByClass(RainfallAnalyzer.class);
        job.setMapperClass(RainfallMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(RainfallReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.exit(success ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

This is the code i am working with, i can compile the class file and both mapper and reducer. but when i am executing it with this command
`hadoop jar RainfallAnalyzer.jar RainfallAnalyzer {Input Directory} {Output Directory}`
I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RainfallAnalyzer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:241)
```

I am running the Terminal in the same folder as the jar file is in.

I tried using multiple methods of running a hadoop application and it still wont budge. Been at this problem for days. The file compiles properly but i get this problem when executing it

Comment: How are you building the jar? Does the jar have a file `RainfallAnalyzer` in its root?

Comment: Compiling code isn't the same as bundling class files into a jar. Are you using Maven/Gradle?

Comment: I am not using maven/gradle @OneCricketeer

Comment: Yes, All the files are in the same folder @BenWatson

Comment: `I am not using maven/gradle` so how are you creating a jar?

Comment: @BenWatson using jar cvf , do you suggest i use maven?

Comment: Yes. Use one of those. Mapreduce has transitive dependencies that will not be included by just `jar cvf` command. Also worth pointing out that no one really writes mapreduce code anymore. Spark or Flink are more common

Answer (score 0):

Your Java classes need to be in a package for them to be found. The error indicates it's trying to find a class in the default package, and you've included no `package` line in your code.

I have runnable Gradle examples on my github, by the way. https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox